# How to find values from a raster based on another one?

Tags: r

Assuming I have these rasters:

```
 library(raster)
 r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
 r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
 r2[] <- runif(ncell(r2)) / 2
 r3[] <- runif(ncell(r3)) * 1.5
 s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
```

And I have this categorical raster:

```
  rs <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
  rs[] <-c(5,10,21,36,15)
```

I would like to compute the mean of all pixels in the stack `s` that correspond to `5,10, etc (all values in rs)`.
so obtain something like this:

```
        r1   r2    r3
5       ?     ?      ?
10       ?      ?      ?
21       ?    ?        ?
36
15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the "zonal" mean:

```
set.seed(1)
z <- zonal(s, rs, mean)
round(z, 2)
     zone layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
[1,]    5    0.53    0.26    0.55
[2,]   10    0.50    0.23    0.51
[3,]   15    0.53    0.30    0.83
[4,]   21    0.52    0.22    0.71
[5,]   36    0.51    0.28    0.67
>
```